# Error: Unknown provider: $elementProvider <- $element

Tags: routes, angularjs

i am trying to use routing in angularjs application as follows:

app.js

```
    angular.module('productapp', []).
    config(['$routeProvider', function($routeProvider) {
    $routeProvider.
        when('/productapp', {templateUrl: 'partials/productList.html',   controller: productsCtrl}).
        //~ when('/productapp/:phoneId', {templateUrl: 'partials/phone-detail.html', controller: PhoneDetailCtrl}).
        otherwise({redirectTo: '/productapp'});
}]);
```

controller.js

```
function productsCtrl($scope, $http, $element) {
        //~ $scope.url = 'php/search.php'; // The url of our search
        // The function that will be executed on button click (ng-click="search()")
        $http.get('php/products.php').success(function(data){
            alert("hi");
            $scope.products = data;
        });

    $scope.search = function() {
        var elem = angular.element($element);
        var dt = $(elem).serialize();
        dt = dt+"&action=index";
        alert(dt);
        console.log($(elem).serialize());
        $http({
            method: 'POST',
            url: 'php/products.php',
            data: dt,
            headers: {'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'}
        }).success(function(data, status) {
            //console.log(data);
            $scope.products = data; // Show result from server in our <pre></pre> element
        }).error(function(data, status) {
            $scope.data = data || "Request failed";
            $scope.status = status;
        });
    }; //....
```

index.html

```
<html ng-app = "productapp">
<head>
<title>Search form with AngualrJS</title>
        <script src="../angular-1.0.1.min.js"></script>
        <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script src="js/products.js"></script>
        <script src="js/app.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <div ng-view></div>
</body>
</html>
```

productList.html

```
<div>
            <label>Search</label>
            <input type="text" name="searchKeywords" ng-model="keywords" placeholder="enter name..." value="{{rs.name}}">
            <button type="submit" ng-click="search()">Search</button>
            <label>Add New Product:</label>
            <input type="text" name="keywords" ng-model="rs.name" placeholder="enter name..." value="{{rs.name}}">
            <input type="text" name="desc" ng-model="rs.description" placeholder="enter description..." value="{{rs.description}}">
            <button type="submit" ng-click="add()">Add</button>
            <button type="submit" ng-click="save(rs.product_id)">Save</button>

            <p>enter product name...</p>
            <table border='2'>
                <th>Name</th>
                <th>Description</th>
                <th>Edit</th>
                <th>Delete</th>

                <tr ng-repeat="product in products" ng-model = 'products'>
                <td>{{product.name}}</td>
                <td>{{product.description}}</td>
                    <td><a href='' ng-click = "fetch(product.product_id)">edit</a></td>
                    <td> <a href='' ng-click = "del(product.product_id)" ng-hide="isHidden">delete</a></td>
                </tr>
            </table>
</div>
```

when i run this code i get the following error in the console(of google chrome) :

```
Error: Unknown provider: $elementProvider <- $element
```

i came to know that this error occurred because i am using the `$element` in the productsCtrl. but then what should i do?
how do i solve this problem?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

<strike>$element is not injectable (it is not something that is registered with the AngularJS injector), so you can't pass it into your controller that way.</strike>

Your productsCtrl, and hence your search() method, has access to all of the form data because of the ng-model directives, which setup two-way binding between your form and your controller.  E.g., inside your search() method, you already have access to the keywords as $scope.keywords.

See if this works for you:

```
var dt = $($scope.keywords).serialize();  // or maybe just  $scope.keywords.serialize();
```

**Update**: this fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/michelpa/NP6Yk/ seems to inject $element into a controller.  (I'm not sure how/why that works... maybe because the controller is attached to a form tag/directive?)

**Update #2**: injecting $element into a controller is possible, but that "goes deep against the angular way" -- https://groups.google.com/d/msg/angular/SYglWP_x7ew/lFtb75NWNWUJ

As mentioned in the comments, I think the answer to your question is to put your form data into a single, larger object and send that along in your $http request.

Comment: keywords is the name of just one textbox. i use $element as i want to serialize the content of all the form fields. if i use $scope.field then i have to specify all the fields manually. is there any other way round?

Comment: Reading around, it seems you shouldn't have to use jQuery's serialize() method at all.  See if these help (note that $xhr was replaced with $http):
https://groups.google.com/d/msg/angular/ySpF18OiETo/uyKCM1oWknAJ and 
http://deansofer.com/posts/view/14/AngularJs-Tips-and-Tricks-UPDATED#serialize -- here Dean suggests putting all your form data into a larger object, hence <input type="text" name="searchKeywords" ng-model="data.keywords"

Comment: thanks mate! solution given in https://groups.google.com/forum/#!msg/angular/ySpF18OiETo/uyKCM1oWknAJ works. i used $(elem.parent()).serialize() to make it work.

Comment: yeah, that would not be a very "angular" way of doing things. I would have a model containing an array of objects and for each of those ng-foreach generate the form elements, then just serialize the object.

Answer (score -1):

I don't think you need to inject $element into your controller. Rather, try passing it as an argument to the function that needs it. I'm not sure why exactly this works:

```
<a ng-click="search($element)">
```

Comment: Does that really work for you? It doesn't work for me.