# Karma angular unknown provider element

Tags: angularjs, karma-runner

I'm getting this error when trying to test a controller in Karma:

```
Error: [$injector:unpr] http://errors.angularjs.org/1.2.14/$injector/unp
r?p0=%24elementProvider%20%3C-%20%24element
at c:/js/libs/angular/angular1.2.14/angular.min.js:32
at c (c:/js/libs/angular/angular1.2.14/angular.min.js:30)
at c:/js/libs/angular/angular1.2.14/angular.min.js:32
at c (c:/js/libs/angular/angular1.2.14/angular.min.js:30)
at d (c:/js/libs/angular/angular1.2.14/angular.min.js:30)
at c:/js/libs/angular/angular1.2.14/angular.min.js:31
at c:/js/libs/angular/angular1.2.14/angular.min.js:63
at c:/tests/unit/widget_tests/myTest.test.js:13
at d (c:/js/libs/angular/angular1.2.14/angular.min.js:30)
at workFn (c:/js/libs/angular/angular1.2.14/angular-mocks.js:2160)
```

I'm including all the angular files in `karma.conf.js` and compiling the controller like so:

```
var $scope, $http, $translate;
    beforeEach(module('myApp.services'));
    beforeEach(module('myApp.directives'));

beforeEach(inject(function ($rootScope, $controller, _$httpBackend_) {
        $scope = $rootScope.$new();
        $controller('myController', {$scope : $scope});

    }));

    describe('Initialization :', function(){
        it('Should ', function() {
        })
    })
})
```

Comment: You forgot to specify `$translate` in injected fields: `function ($rootScope, $controller, _$httpBackend_, $translate)`

Comment: sorry, I should of removed the setTranslate, in the actual code the service is being injected.

Comment: Can you provide the stack for the error with the line numbers?

Comment: Updated with full error.

Comment: Do you use $element or jquery somewhere in your code ? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12494825/error-unknown-provider-elementprovider-element

Comment: Yes it's used in the controller.

Comment: That answer's solved the problem, though the fiddles gone.  Do you know how to inject the $element / mock it somehow?

Comment: One plunker or jsfiddle would be so useful in this kind of OP.

Answer (score 6):

I needed to inject the `$element` into the controller, though compiling the full directive is another option.

`$controller('myController', {$scope : $scope, $element :$('<div></div>')});`

Posting this as the duplicate question is missing an example.

Comment: This was what I needed. One slight improvement: `angular.element('<div></div>')` removes the jquery dependency

Answer (score 0):

Your `$scope` variable is `undefined` so far.
By the way, the following should work:

```
var $scope, $httpBackend;

beforeEach(function() {
  module('myApp', 'myApp.services', 'myApp.directives'));
  inject(function ($rootScope, $controller, _$httpBackend_) {
    $scope = $rootScope.$new();
    $httpBackend = _$httpBackend_;
    $controller('myController', {$scope : $scope});
  }));
});

describe('Initialization :', function(){
    it('Should ', function() {
    })
});
```

Comment: Very hard to "guess" the exact reason of this fuzzy error without any accurate stack. It may depend on his context that he doesn't provide. At least, if the code I provide doesn't work, he can track other zones to have better chance to find the issue.

Comment: Sorry,in the code scope is defined, I edited it out.